# Trouble selecting q-q plot settings with statsmodels. Do any of these plots properly compare the sample quantiles to theoretical normal quantiles?

Tags: statsmodels, qq-plot

I have an array of over 6,000 data points and am trying to show whether they follow a normal distribution. Statsmodels (the library I'm using to generate plots) gives the option of using a 45-degree line for reference, a standardized line, or a line fit to quartiles. According to the documentation, for the standardized line, the expected order statistics are scaled by the standard deviation of the given sample and have the mean added to them. This is how the plot looks when using a standardized line:

[image]

You can also generate the reference line using the 'q' setting where a "line is fit through the quartiles" according to the documentation:

[image]

Note, the result is slightly different with the quartile setting compared to the standardized line setting (see near top right of q-q plot).

Lastly, there is a setting for "fit". According to the library documentation, if "fit" is set to False, "loc, scale, and distargs are passed to the distribution." If "fit" is set to True, "the parameters for dist are fit automatically using dist.fit. The quantiles are formed from the standardized data, after subtracting the fitted loc and dividing by the fitted scale."

The plots in the two above images were generated with "fit" set to True. With fit set to False (and using the quartile line setting), the plot looks like this:

[image]

where the scale of the y-axis has changed.

However, if I use "fit" set to False and the line setting as '45', I get this:

[image]

Which does not look right.

Which q-q plot settings are most correct for simply comparing quantiles of sample dataset to a theoretical normal distribution?

The documentation can be found here:

https://www.statsmodels.org/0.9.0/generated/statsmodels.graphics.gofplots.qqplot.html

Thank you for the help!

Comment: The second and third look the same except for location and scale of the sample quantiles axis.  The fourth looks weird because the $45^\circ$ line through the origin only makes any kind of sense if you think the theoretical and sample quantiles should have the same location and scale in the null hypothesis (as they are forced to do in the first).

Answer (score 4):

> Do any of these plots properly compare the sample quantiles to theoretical normal quantiles?

Sure, though arguably it might depend on how you're defining "properly".

> trying to show whether they follow a normal distribution

You can't show that data was drawn from a normal distribution. You may be able to show that a normal population distribution is highly implausible or even impossible, but no matter how consistent your data are with normality, there's always going to be distributions closer to any set of data than the normal is, *even if you simulate data from a normal distribution*.

In this particular case your data *cannot* be drawn from a normal population, it's *clearly* discrete (or at best mixed). It also looks like it's strictly positive, or at least non-negative, so again, cannot be drawn from a normal population. Not that it necessarily matters much, in practice no real variable is actually normal. What matters is the extent to which the non-normality you have impacts what you're trying to do[1].

1. It may be that no normality assumption is needed. It depends on what you're doing with it.
2. Even when there is a normality assumption underlying some inferential procedure, in many cases, even a diagnostic check of normality may be misplaced. For example, if you're trying to model a response in terms of a set of predictor variables, the marginal distribution of the response variable isn't relevant for anything.
3. Even where normality is assumed, the non-normality may be barely consequential to the properties of your inference that you're most concerned about.
4. Even where it may be consequential, it may be possible to avoid that specific assumption -- importantly, without changing the hypothesis. For example, a more suitable parametric assumption may be possible, but there's also the possibility of using a very similar inferential method (often with the same test statistic)  without a specific distributional assumption.

What are these values in the plot? Are they some kind of ratio?

> Note, the result is slightly different with the quartile setting compared to the standardized line setting (see near top right of q-q plot).

Sure, a parameter estimated from quartiles won't match one estimated from sample mean and s.d.

> However, if I use "fit" set to False and the line setting as '45', I get this:

In that case, the 45 degree line would be for cases where you can specify the population mean and standard deviation (specified population parameters).

> Which q-q plot settings are most correct for simply comparing quantiles of sample dataset to a theoretical normal distribution?

The first three pictures are all perfectly reasonable choices. There is no real sense in which one is "most" correct. It's a diagnostic plot, and the line is just there as a visual aid to help you assess deviations from linearity. The choice of axis scale is immaterial unless you are specifying a particular normal distribution.

---

[1]: As George Box put it: "*Remember that all models are wrong; the practical question is how wrong do they have to be to not be useful.*"
https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/George_E._P._Box#Empirical_Model-Building_and_Response_Surfaces_(1987)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response. I don't necessarily need to make statements about a normal distribution (not performing a t-test or anything), but simply need to make some accurate statements about the data and its distribution

Comment: Also, sorry if this is a silly question. Since the data is discrete and cannot be drawn from a normal distribution, is it meaningful or customary at all to plot quantiles against a normal distribution line as above?

Comment: 1. You have 6000 data points. If it's actually a random sample from some process/population of interest, you can describe that population cdf with a good deal of precision without mention of any  parametric model... 2. No harm in looking at that plot. But for discrete data I'd usually use something else

Comment: What sort of thing is being measured here? Why such a peak just below 60?

Comment: Thank you. The sample is a set of topic-relevance scores for words in a document corpus (natural language processing) ranging from 0 to 100. Would a box plot be better for this?

Comment: Specifically, each term gets a topic relevance score for how well it reflects the salient topics of the broader corpus (collection of documents). Over 6000 terms are in the set

Comment: 1. No a boxplot would be a considerably worse choice. Why not something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPlFR.png)? 2. I'm not familiar with the area, but its not clear why you'd need to describe the distribution of topic relevance across a collection of distinct terms at all.

Comment: Thank you for the time you put into answering this